# how to create Jqgrid using jsp

Tags: json, jsp, jqgrid

I am very new in jquery and json.i know jsp and java
in my project job i have to implement a data grid same like shows in http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html#
i this example site i need a datagrid using Json object.
i explore all in internet but i cant find any help of that.

please provide me an example with uses jqgrid json using jsp -servlet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally converted the PHP code to jsp code of jqgrid:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {

    jQuery("#list10").jqGrid({

        url:'griddata.jsp',
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client'],
        colModel:[{name:'id',index:'id', width:55},{name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90},{name:'name',index:'name', width:100}],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[5,7,10],
    pager: '#pager10',
    sortname: 'id',
        datatype: 'json',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
    multiselect: false,
    imgpath: "themes/basic/images",
    caption: "Invoice Header",
    onSelectRow: function(ids) {

                        jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid().setGridParam({url : 'getsubdata.jsp?id='+ids}).trigger("reloadGrid")
                        jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setCaption',"Invoice Detail: "+ids)

                        }

        });

    jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager10',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});


<!-- subgrid start-->

    jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid({
                                url:'getsubdata.jsp?id=0',
                                datatype: 'json',
                                colNames:['No','Item', 'Qty', 'Unit','Line Total'],
                                colModel:[
                                        {name:'num',index:'num' },
                                        {name:'item',index:'item'},
                                        {name:'qty',index:'qty',align:"center"},
                                        {name:'unit',index:'unit', align:"center"},     
                                        {name:'linetotal',index:'linetotal',align:"center", sortable:false, search:false}
                                ],
                                rowNum:5,
                                rowList:[5,10,20],
                                pager: '#pager10_d',
                                sortname: 'item',
                                viewrecords: true,
                                sortorder: "asc",
                                multiselect: true,
                                imgpath: "themes/basic/images",
                                caption:"Invoice Detail"
                        }).navGrid('#pager10_d',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});


     }//function
    );//ready
```

In this code i have created two jsp file .

First one code is below

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.util.ArrayList,net.sf.json.*" %>
<%
        String rows=request.getParameter("rows");

        String pageno=request.getParameter("page");
        String cpage=pageno;

        Connection connect = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet rs= null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=root");
        statement = connect.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM grid ");

        int count=0;
        rs.last();
        count=rs.getRow(); 

        int  pageval=0;
        pageval=(count/Integer.parseInt(rows));

        int limitstart=0;

        limitstart=(Integer.parseInt(rows)*Integer.parseInt(pageno))-Integer.parseInt(rows);
        int total=count/Integer.parseInt(rows);
        String totalrow=String.valueOf(total+1);

        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM grid limit "+limitstart+","+rows);  


        JSONObject responcedata=new JSONObject();
        net.sf.json.JSONArray cellarray=new net.sf.json.JSONArray();

         responcedata.put("total",totalrow);
        responcedata.put("page",cpage);
        responcedata.put("records",count);

        net.sf.json.JSONArray cell=new net.sf.json.JSONArray();
        net.sf.json.JSONObject cellobj=new net.sf.json.JSONObject();

        int i=1;
       while(rs.next())
           {
                cellobj.put("id",rs.getString(1));
                cell.add(rs.getString(1));
                cell.add(rs.getString(2));
                cell.add(rs.getString(3));

        cellobj.put("cell",cell);
        cell.clear();
        cellarray.add(cellobj);
        i++;
       }
        responcedata.put("rows",cellarray);
        out.println(responcedata);

%>
```

And the secound JSP meams getsubdata.jsp file is below:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.util.ArrayList,net.sf.json.*" %>
<%
        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        String rows=request.getParameter("rows");
        String pageno=request.getParameter("page");
        String cpage=pageno;


        JSONObject mysubdata=new JSONObject();
        JSONArray subarray = new JSONArray();
        Connection connect = null;
   Statement statement = null;

 ResultSet rs= null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=root");
        statement = connect.createStatement();

        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM subgrid where gridid='"+id+"'");  

        int count=0;
        rs.last();
        count=rs.getRow(); 

        int  pageval=0;
        pageval=(count/Integer.parseInt(rows));

        int limitstart=0;

        limitstart=(Integer.parseInt(rows)*Integer.parseInt(pageno))-Integer.parseInt(rows);
        int total=count/Integer.parseInt(rows);
        String totalrow=String.valueOf(total+1);

        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM subgrid where gridid='"+id+"' limit "+limitstart+","+rows);  

        JSONObject responcedata=new JSONObject();
        net.sf.json.JSONArray cellarray=new net.sf.json.JSONArray();

        responcedata.put("total",totalrow);
        responcedata.put("page",cpage);
        responcedata.put("records",count);

        net.sf.json.JSONArray cell=new net.sf.json.JSONArray();
        net.sf.json.JSONObject cellobj=new net.sf.json.JSONObject();

        int ii=1;
       while(rs.next()) 

       {
                cellobj.put("id",""+ii);

                //cell.add(rs.getString(1));
                cell.add(rs.getString(1));
                cell.add(rs.getString(2));
                cell.add(rs.getString(3));
                cell.add(rs.getString(4));
                cell.add(rs.getString(4));

        cellobj.put("cell",cell);
        cell.clear();
        cellarray.add(cellobj);
        ii++;
       }
        responcedata.put("rows",cellarray);
        out.println(responcedata);
```

And the secound JSP meams getsubdata.jsp file is below

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.util.ArrayList,net.sf.json.*" %>
<%
        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        String rows=request.getParameter("rows");
        String pageno=request.getParameter("page");
        String cpage=pageno;


        JSONObject mysubdata=new JSONObject();
        JSONArray subarray = new JSONArray();
        Connection connect = null;
   Statement statement = null;

 ResultSet rs= null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=root");
        statement = connect.createStatement();

        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM subgrid where gridid='"+id+"'");  

        int count=0;
        rs.last();
        count=rs.getRow(); 

        int  pageval=0;
        pageval=(count/Integer.parseInt(rows));

        int limitstart=0;

        limitstart=(Integer.parseInt(rows)*Integer.parseInt(pageno))-Integer.parseInt(rows);
        int total=count/Integer.parseInt(rows);
        String totalrow=String.valueOf(total+1);

        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM subgrid where gridid='"+id+"' limit "+limitstart+","+rows);  

        JSONObject responcedata=new JSONObject();
        net.sf.json.JSONArray cellarray=new net.sf.json.JSONArray();

        responcedata.put("total",totalrow);
        responcedata.put("page",cpage);
        responcedata.put("records",count);

        net.sf.json.JSONArray cell=new net.sf.json.JSONArray();
        net.sf.json.JSONObject cellobj=new net.sf.json.JSONObject();

        int ii=1;
       while(rs.next()) 

       {
                cellobj.put("id",""+ii);

                //cell.add(rs.getString(1));
                cell.add(rs.getString(1));
                cell.add(rs.getString(2));
                cell.add(rs.getString(3));
                cell.add(rs.getString(4));
                cell.add(rs.getString(4));

        cellobj.put("cell",cell);
        cell.clear();
        cellarray.add(cellobj);
        ii++;
       }
        responcedata.put("rows",cellarray);
        out.println(responcedata);
```

Comment: Still any one can not get success please let me know i will help him/her

Thanks

Dhrumil Shah

Comment: Hi Dhrumil Shah can you please tell me the table strucre?

Comment: @Rakesh
I cant get you. what is the need for DB Table struct.Columns you want to display in grid put in 
                cell.add(rs.getString(1));
                cell.add(rs.getString(2));
                cell.add(rs.getString(3));
this code and also put the names of grid column model. you will get the result. 
i think you get my point.
If you still have issue please ask in details.

Answer (score 0):

You've really explored the entire internet?  Impressive.  All the demo's on the jqGrid demo page show the code necessary, even the server side code.  You'll simply need to convert their PHP into JSP/Servlet code.

Comment: Ya man Thanks for your reply. actually i have problem to convert PHP code in jsp else part i know. if you help me in converting this, its Hartley appreciate. Dhrumil Shah

Comment: Then you should post the relevant code that you are having problems with in a new question.  Or edit this question with more information.